# dynamic button not firing

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to generate a bit of html that includes a button.  For some reason, I can't get the button event to fire for the generated button.

The generated html looks fine when I view source...I also looked through Firebug and I don't see anything wrong....the button click event is not being fired for the dynamically generated button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnSearch).click(function () {
         var html = "";
         html += "<tr><td>Test</td></tr>";
         html += "<tr><td>Test 2</td></tr>";
         html += "<tr><td><input id="btnTest" type="button" value="Test Button" /></td></tr>";

        $(html).appendTo("#TestTable");
    });


    $("#btnTest").on("click", function () {
         alert('hey');
    });

});
```

My static html is simply:

```
<table id="TestTable"></table>
```

Comment: See Leeish's answer, you need to use delegation here

Comment: are u sure you dont have a javascript error saying that $("#btnTest") does not exist or something...btnTest test exist if you click on btnSearch how could you apply a click event on a button that does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '#btnTest' function () {
     alert('hey');
});
```

You need to read the `.on` documentation and understand what it's doing better. It's different than the old `.live` method.

Comment: thanks, you forgot a comma, but it works great.  Why does this work and my original function not?  I don't see any real different between the two.

Comment: Read the documentation. Essentially it attaches a listener to the `BODY` which is always present. When a click is fired on the body, it then checks to see if it was on the `#btnTest`. If so it runs the code. Your code still only attaches it to the `#btTest` element that existed when the code was ran I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I have not much knowledge about how jquery "on" method works.
So I have made a few changes in your code which may solve your purpose.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
            $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
                 var html = "";
                 html += "<tr><td>Test</td></tr>";
                 html += "<tr><td>Test 2</td></tr>";
                 html += '<tr><td><input id="btnTest" type="button" value="Test Button" onclick="myfun()"/></td></tr>';
                $(html).appendTo("#TestTable");
            });


            /*$("body").on("click",'btnTest' ,function () {
                 alert('hey');
            });
        */

        });

        function myfun()
        {alert("hey");}
```

Answer (score 0):

put

```
$("#btnTest").on("click", function () {
     alert('hey');
});
```

inside the click event function of the previous button (btnSearch) .. be aware that if you click several times on search button you have several btnTest... normal ?

Comment: the syntax of .on is invalid

Comment: maybe he should use bind function but I dont see why on function is invalid here